# Lock user account and still be able to log in through ssh public key?

Tags: linux, user-management

is it possible to have a user account in Linux that can only login through its SSH public key?

I thought to simply do `sudo passwd -l myuser` and lock the account (so I don't need to generate some random and secure password) and allow to login only through SSH public key. Unfortunately this does not work (log says: User myuser not allowed because account is locked).

Thanks

Comment: If the password is unknown and you only allow public key auth, for all intents and purposes, you've created an account that can only log in with keys.

Answer (score 0):

Just generate a random string and pass it to the `useradd` command. If nothing else, `useradd -p '*NP*' <userid>` will do the trick.